# Reloading TableView on iPhone from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a FirstViewController, which is a UITableViewController, as well as delegate and dataSource. It has the table view.

I have another class, FeedParser, that parses the data - but after it's done parsing, I need it to go and refresh the UITableView or else it won't show anything.

This is probably a stupid question, so forgive me, but how should I go about calling FirstViewController's tableView.reloadData from FeedParser?

Is there a method to return that view?

Thanks!

Comment: when did the feedparser class called?

Comment: Is feedParser a seperate viewController?

Comment: FeedParser class is instantiated and called from the AppDelegate upon loading the app.

Comment: feedParser is not a viewController by itself.

Comment: The parsed data is stored in an array or what? Is that the dataSource for tabelView?

Comment: Yes, parsed data is stored in an array, which currently resides with the app delegate (yes I know, not good practice - I'll move it to a singleton soon).

Comment: And yes, the dataSource for tableView comes from this, though it is not directly taken - it's parsed again through other stuff first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Register the view controller to receive notifications that the data has been changed, and have it refresh the table when it receives one. Then have the parser send it out.

Registering for it is easy:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(yourRefreshMethodHere:)
                                             name:@"YourNotificationName"
                                           object:nil];
```

Your refresh method needs to be set up to receive these notifications, along these lines:

```
- (void)reloadTable:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [self.yourTableName reloadData];
}
```

And it's important to stop observing in your ViewDidUnload:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Then in the parser you need to simply add this when it's complete:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"YourNotificationName" 
                                                    object:nil];
```

The view controller (and anyone else observing the notification with that name) will get the message and perform its task.

Comment: Ah using some type of notifying thing occurred to me - I tried to implement my own via the app delegate but I didn't want something to be checking every so often.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! (And I'm not used to the whole enter is submit comment thing yet; I meant to put this together). Thanks so much! I'd vote that up if I could but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: Oh and it also helps me with some other problems I had. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, glad it's working for you. Notifications opened up a ton of solutions for me, too. (Though you can't vote it up, you can check the checkmark next to the answer to show that it solved your problem -- that'll also help your rep.)

Comment: found this solution good .. voting up on behalf of Kevin (he dont have reps to vote up)

Comment: Great answer! This is a God send! Working with threads and data is a bit tricky in Objective-C, this is a HUGE help!

Answer (score 3):

Simple method,

Create a object for your `FirstViewController` in appDelegate, assign property and synthesize it.

In `ViewDidLoad` of FirstViewController,

```
firstViewControllerObj = self;
```

In `feedParser.m`, after the parsing done code as follows,

```
[appDelegate.firstViewControllerObj.tabelView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just store a reference to FirstViewController on your app delegate, then call `[appDelegate.firstViewController.tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: I'm pretty new at this but I don't think I can do that - I'm not loading FirstViewController from the app delegate.